# Work VPN only slow on at my house

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, firewall, lan

I am connecting to my work VPN from home. It is EXTREMELY SLOW. network admin and sys admin see no issues on the VPN side. IE, it is working properly from them when they are on the vpn and the bandwidth usage is low.

I believe there is something weird with my home internet connection that is causing this issue but I don't know what it could be because I have not changed any settings. (VPN used to work fine with no issues at all before).

I tried rebooting, reconnecting to vpn, resetting my home internet. I did a speed test on home internet and download was 15mbps, and upload was 1.7ish. I am mainly looking for advice on what I could look into to try and diagnose the problem.

When i did a traceroute while on the VPN, it should all the repsonses within 40-50ms so that seems normal. My ISP is at&t and my at&t router is 3801HGV.

I am connecting to the vpn by just using Windows 7's "add vpn connection". Security options are: Type of VPN: automatic. Data encryption: Require encryption. Again though, i have changed no settings on VPN or wireless since it starting being slow...

Thanks Guys

Comment: If you believe the issue is your home connection then contact your ISP?    You don't indicate what "extremely slow" is exactly.

Comment: by extremely slow i mean that when i connect and try to connect to work servers it is slow to even keep up with typing

Answer (score 1):

I have seen VPNs choke when using certain home based routers.  Try connecting your machine directly to your cable modem(?) and test your VPN.  If it works fine, then your router is the culprit.  Easy enough to fix... routers are cheap.